# Can I get the duplicate close link on this question changed?

Tags: support, status-completed

On [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/751042/minimise-launcher-icon-ubuntu-14), I voted to close as a duplicate of [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41241/shortcut-to-change-launcher-hide-setting) but the user wanted to change the icon size not hide the launcher, so it was a duplicate of [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/519678/unity-14-04-set-launcher-icon-size-via-command-line).

However the OP accepted the original duplicate and the comments were deleted, now it is closed as the wrong duplicate.

Comment: Done that (and finally got to use the dupehammer). :)

Comment: Was this just to get that specific question fixed? If not: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14860/we-should-be-able-to-vote-to-change-the-close-reason

Comment: I just wanted this fixed, but I already voted on that question. Would of been a lot easier if I could of just changed my reason. :)

Comment: I agree. I'd say that someone should bring it to Meta.SE, but they did that already: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/207768/302251.